# d3.v4.js Line graph zoom - lines get out of the graph + I want xAxis to change respectively

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linegraph

I have a multiline graph. The zooming is working fine except that when I zoom in, the lines get out of the graph and I want to fix that. Also, I don't know why the dates on my xAxis stay static and doesn't change respectively when I zoom in.

My code for the brush and zoom functions:

```
function brushed() {
          if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return;

          var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();

          x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));

          plot.selectAll(".line")
            .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
            .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
          plot.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);

          svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
              .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
              .translate(-s[0], 0));
        }

        function zoomed() {
          if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return;

          var t = d3.event.transform;

          x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());

          plot.selectAll(".line")
            .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
            .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
          plot.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);

          slider.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
        }
```

An image of my graph:
[You can see the lines that get out of the graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BYtD.png)
[Edit] 
 Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kqRxO7TFKVy2I2olKBBA?p=preview) with my whole code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (add line 195 of your code on plunker) :

```
country.append("path")
          .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
```

You need to apply the clip to the lines (or anything else) that overflows. In your code you just defined the clip but did not apply it anywhere.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to check my css and as it seems I forgot to add this line: clip-path: url(#clip); for my .line. That's what it was missing.